# JQuery - Open modal for dynamic links

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog

I have several links and I need to open a modal window with a form so the user can upload a image.

I need to send the link ID to this modal window so I can make the correct upload.

I really don't know how to do that because my links have the same Id, otherwise I need to create a modal function for each link.

How do I do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ID's are supposed to be unique according to html standards. So you can add a dialog to a link based on the class. Which will be best way to do..

Working example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/4/)

Answer (score 1):

I don't fully understand what you're trying to do with the links, but nevertheless:

1. html IDs must be unique within the document, so if that's the source of your problem, you just need to fix that
2. modal dialogs can be created with jQuery UI: http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

Answer (score 0):

You use unique ids for everything i.e.

```
<sometag id=thisdynid<?php echo your_dynamic_id_in_loop; ?> >
```

So now you have dynamic HTML ID elements.

Now your jQuery handlers will be coded into your loop as well.

```
$('#thisdynid<?php echo your_dynamic_id_in_loop; ?>').event.function(){
function code here.

}
```

Now you have dynamic elements with dynamic event handlers, couldn't be simpler. You can also use the 'name' attribute to fetch the ids to pass through to your php page.

```
<sometag id="thisdynid<?php echo your_dynamic_id_in_loop; ?>" name="<?php echo your_dynamic_id_in_loop; ?>">
```

Then:

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'your.php',
        method: 'GET',
        data: 'ID=' + $(this).attr('name'),
        success: function(data) {
```

etc etc.. hope this helps

Comment: You use unique ids for everything i.e.

code <sometag id="<?php echo uniqueid;?>" name="<?php echo uniqueid;?>">

$('#thisdynid<?php echo uniqueid;?>').event.function(){

function code here.

}